# How many 'zero' elements in $\mathrm{A}+\mathrm{B}$ after randomly letting one entry in $\mathrm{A, B}$ be $0$ for $m$ times,respectively?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, random-variables, sampling

Both $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{B}$ are $d$-dimensional vector with all the elements being $1$. Then we randomly and uniformly pick one element from $\mathrm{A}$ with replacement, and let it be $0$. We repeat this procedure for $m$ times. Then we also independently do the same thing for vector $\mathrm{B}$. Assuming $2m\leq d$. Then, what is the expectation for how many zero elements in $\mathrm{A}+\mathrm{B}$? Thanks very much for your help. We know that we at most have $2m$ zero elements.

Comment: Are these $0$s and $1$s binary digits, or real numbers? I mean, does $1+1=0$ hold?

Comment: When you "repeat this procedure $m$ times" might you choose the same element of $A$ more then once?

Comment: If an element of $A$ is once chosen it becomes $0$, then it can't be chosen next time, right?

Comment: @Crostul   it is real number i.e. 1+1=2. Yes, I might choose the the same element of A. If an element of A is 0, I may still choose it. Thanks.

Comment: @Henry  Yes, I might choose the the same element of A.

Comment: @Samrat Mukhopadhyay  If an element of A is 0, I may still choose it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, then after you choose a $0$, you toggle it to $1$, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The probability a particular element of $A$ is $1$ after $d$ picks is $\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^d$.

The probability a particular element of $A$ is $0$ after $d$ picks is $1-\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^d$.

The probability a particular element of $A+B$ is $0$ after $d$ picks is $\left(1-\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^d\right)^2$.

The expected number of zero elements of $A+B$ after $d$ picks is $m\left(1-\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^d\right)^2$.